# How to grant access for all authenticated users?

Tags: java, spring-security

Need to grant access to users without any role using Spring Security. Anyone how process authentication must be granted to access any URL. So can I do that by something like this or may be somehow else?

```
<http auto-config='true'>
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ALL" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" filters="none" />
  <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" />
</http>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are probably looking for IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY or IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED or IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY

also check http://www.acegisecurity.org/acegi-security/apidocs/org/acegisecurity/vote/AuthenticatedVoter.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually you just need to create your own AccessDecisionManager, and your own AccessDecisionVoter(s) and pass them into the  block like this:

```
<http .... access-decsion-manager="myAccessManager">
  .....
</http>

<bean id="myAccessManager" class="org.springframework.security.vote.AffirmativeBased">
   <property name="decisionVoters">
      <list>
         <bean id="myVoter" class=[some subclass of AccessDecisionVoter] />
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

This is not the 100% solution, but it should get you started on the right path.  The "auto-config" setup in Spring Security creates a lot of these classes in the background, and automatically loads them if there are no other beans of the correct classes available.